# JPA & RequestFactory: Persistence of Foreign Keys

Tags: gwt, jpa, jpa-2.0, requestfactory

In my JPA Entity class I have:

```
@Entity
public class Booking {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "BOOKING", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BOOKING")
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private User user;

// ...
}
```

In my GWT View I have:

```
    MainRequestFactory.BookingRequest bookingRequest = reqFactory.bookingRequest();
    BookingProxy bookingProxy = bookingRequest.create(BookingProxy.class);
    UserProxy userProxy = bookingRequest.create(UserProxy.class);

    userProxy.setId(12);

    bookingProxy.setUser(userProxy);

    Request<Void> persistRequest = bookingRequest.persist().using(bookingProxy);
    persistRequest.fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void response) {
            GWT.log("persisted");
        }
    });
```

/////////////////////

`Users` and `Bookings` persistence without the User Constraint works fine. But with the above code I want/have to assign the user with the ID "12" to a newly created booking. But I cannot assign a new booking to an already existing user ID 12. I get the following error:

> [EL Warning]: 2011-07-05
>   18:48:45.464--UnitOfWork(267787945)--Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services -
>   2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception:
>   org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException:
>   GDS Exception. 335544665. violation of
>   PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   "INTEG_388" on table "USERS2"

It's because an user with the ID "12" already exists and JPA wants to create a new user with the same ID instead of just creating a new booking with the user ID "12" as its foreign key.

How can I tell `RequestFactory` NOT to create a new user but instead just to assign the user ID of an already existing user to a new booking entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your analysis of the problem is correct.

Instead of creating a User, instead use an EntityManager find() or getReference() to retrieve the existing User item.

Comment: Could you elaborate it a little further? Please keep in mind that I can talk to the domain classes only through RequestFactory's Proxy classes.

Comment: I've tried to replace "setUser(User user) { this.user = user;}" in my Booking.java with setUser(Integer id) {    UserController userController = new UserControllerImpl();
        this.user = userController.getReference(id);} but I've got the same error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the GWT, my quick reading of the docs came across the example requestFactory.employeeRequest().findEmployee(employeeId) using find() rather than create(), I'm guessing, but conceptually this sounds like what you need: finding an existing entry rather than  creating a new one.

Comment: Yep, findUser is the solution! My GWT code: Request<Void> persistRequest = context.setUserReference(userId).using(bookingProxy); My server-side code (Booking Entity): this.setUser(User.findUser(userId)); entityController.create(this);